# New SSD recognized in Windows but not in BIOS (also not bootable) - Samsung 970 Evo plus - Aspire vn 571g

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd, bios

I just bought an ssd (Samsung 970 evo plus nvme M.2) for my aspire vn-571g and I'm trying to install it. The "hardware part" was ok, when I boot my pc on my hdd, and I go to disk management it shows me my new installed ssd.

Now the problem is that I tried to install windows 10 on my ssd thanks to an usb sitck where I put a clean image of windows (thanks to the Microsoft tool) and disconnecting my hdd to boot on the ssd. But I have a screen where it's written "No bootable devices" and when I go to the bios it doesn't show me my ssd.

What I currently now/tried :

Bios Boot mode : UEFI

Secure mode : Disabled

I check on my component that I have a Pci port with at least Max link = 2 and I have one (actually it's the one where my ssd is currently plugged)

Hmmm I dont have anythink else in mind but feel free to ask more questions :)

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: NVME is not supported on that model, you need plain ol M.2 ssd.....https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/473008/ssd-960-evo-nvme-m-2-250gb-on-aspire-vn7-571g-59pm

Comment: From the link you send : "My reply was more than 6 months ago and the situation has changed, you have to install the program HWiNFO64, check the PCI Express ports, if you find a port with maximum link width of 2x or 4x, you can install NVMe drive" and I have one of this port so I think it's compatible no ? 

In addition my system recognize it

Comment: Bios/UEFI firmware can override any hardware the system may have, Acer may have decided not to implement nvme even tho the hardware supports it.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks indeed it seems to be the probleme, do you have any references of ssd that will work on my laptop please ? :)